# Incorrect reference to $this inside callback function of BotMan Conversation's ask method

Tags: php, laravel, chatbot, botman

I am using the BotMan framework in PHP to create a chatbot, and I have encountered an issue with the incorrect reference to `$this` inside a callback function used with the ask method of BotMan's Conversation class.

I have created a DepositConversation class that extends the Conversation class, and I have defined two methods, `askAmount()` and `askPaymentMethod()`, to ask questions to the user. However, when I call $this inside the callback function, which is the second parameter of the ask method, the `$this` reference is incorrect and refers to `BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversation\InlineConversation` instead of `DepositConversation`.

Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
use BotMan\BotMan\BotMan;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations\Conversation;

class DepositConversation extends Conversation
{
    // ...

    public function askAmount()
    {
        $this->ask('What is the amount you want to deposit?', function($answer) {
            // $this refers to BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversation\InlineConversation
            // instead of DepositConversation
            $this->amount = $answer->getText();
            
            // ...
        });
    }

    // ...
}
```

I expected `$this` to refer to the instance of DepositConversation so that I can access the class properties and perform additional operations. However, it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or knows how to resolve this incorrect reference error to `$this` inside a callback function of BotMan Conversation's ask method? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: _"reference is incorrect and refers to InlineConversation instead of DepositConversation."_ How are you determining this? What error are you getting?

Comment: With get_class function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the `ask` method's `Closure` function is bound to another `$this` by using `\Closure:bind`.

There's a simple trick in these use-cases, use `$that` or `$self`.

```php
public function askAmount()
{   
    $that = $this;   // or $self = $this;
    $this->ask('What is the amount you want to deposit?', function($answer) use ($that) {
        $that->amount = $answer->getText();
        // ...
    });
}
```